# cp with interactive don't prompt before overwrite

Tags: bash, cp

I observed a strange behavior cp. Exactly the point is that cp did not ask me for confirmation, even with the option interactive.

A test case looks like this

#### Existing files

```
find * -type f
app/file.txt
test/file.txt
```

#### correct behavior

```
/usr/bin/cp -ip test/file.txt app/
cp: overwrite app//file.txt (yes/no)? yes
```

#### incorrect behavior

```
find test/ -type f | while read line; do /usr/bin/cp -ip $line app/; done
```

Why in the second case `cp` didn't prompt.

Comment: Because stdin is not a terminal

Comment: @jordanm Please post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the simplicity of your while loop, it makes more sense to use `xargs` for your task.  It should also be faster, though I doubt your `test/` directory would be large enough to notice.

```
find test/ -type f -print0 |xargs -o0 cp -ipt app/
```

Note that `-t` is a GNU extension.  If that is problematic, you'd need something like this (to do this with GNU `xargs`, change the `-J` to a `-I`):

```
find test/ -type f -print0 |xargs -o0 -J % cp -ip % app/
```

I used `find -print0` and `xargs -0` so this will work even when your files have spaces in their names.

When `xargs` or the question's `while` loop run in this kind of manner, standard input is consumed and therefore interactivity with the terimal ([tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_(unix)), `/dev/tty`) is not guaranteed.

Using `xargs -o` reopens standard input as `/dev/tty` in each child process to allow for interactivity. Note, this is available in GNU xargs as well as BSD xargs but *not* Busybox xargs or other bare-bones [POSIX xargs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html).

From the GNU findutils man page for xargs(1):

> `-o`, `--open-tty`
>
> Reopen stdin as `/dev/tty` in the child process before executing the command. This is useful if you want `xargs` to run an interactive application.
>
> …
>
> The `-o` option is an extension to the POSIX standard for better compatibility with BSD.

Comment: Even better would be to use find's `-exec … +` feature, which would actually solve OP's problem by leaving STDIN connected to the terminal.

Comment: @derobert – using `-exec` invokes the given command _once per hit_, which is grossly inefficient. `xargs` will actually batch the command to as few invocations as possible given command line length limits. This matters a _lot_ when dealing with massive directory trees. The script's STDIN is not affected here since everything is assigned, so e.g. you will have no issues running `INPUT="$(cat)"` after this.

Comment: @AdamKatz that's with a semicolon at the end, with a plus at the end, find passes as many as possible (limited by the maximum command line length set by the kernel) to each execution.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski – `xargs -o` was the key. Thanks for the tip, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @derobert – I've had bad luck with `find … -exec` in the past but I'll also admit that I don't fully understand it. The `-exec command {} +` variant is interesting; it likely preserves STDIN (now I understand what you meant) but it also gives up on trying to preserve the exit code (which perhaps makes sense since it's unclear which exit code to use when running in more than one batch). This would make for a viable second answer.